# How is score calculated in competitions?

Tags: tony-hawks-pro-skater-1-2

I've been trying to get at least third place in the THPS1 Skate Park competition level, but I keep getting fourth place. What I am noticing is that the score I receive from the judges seems to be mostly unrelated to the score that I receive in-game (or at least, the two scores are not directly correlated). What factors into the score that I receive from the judges?

Comment: So far I've only played the THPS2 levels but I assume they work similarly. I think each of the judges calculate their scores differently and have different priorities. Some will punish you harder when bailing than others. I'm not sure but I think some like grind tricks more while others prefer air tricks. The key to a high score is to have diverse combos and avoid bailing.

Comment: @miva2 My assumption is that at its core the game is the same regardless of what level pack you're playing

Answer (score 2):

The following is based on [this article](https://www.redbull.com/gb-en/tony-hawk-pro-skater-1-2-remaster-competition-tips-guide), which discusses some of the factors that will help achieve higher scores in THPS competitions, as well as my own experiences playing the game and placing in competitions:

- **Don't Bail**: This is probably the most important factor. Bailing incurs a significant score penalty and wastes time. The article suggests that its worth just restarting if you bail early in the first session since the penalty is so steep, and I'd agree anecdotally based on my own experience. The first run in particular is key since it sets you up with a higher score to average from in the later runs, so if you find yourself bailing in the first run its probably better to just restart.
- **Mix it Up**: Use a variety of tricks (flips, grabs, grinds, manuals, etc). Using the special tricks will help boost your score, but I've found in my own experience variety is just as (if not more) important.
- **Use Gaps**: Try to learn where the special gaps are in each map. Judges seem to be impressed by using these special gaps and they will also help to boost your score. You can use the View Gaps function in the Game Options menu to try and find the special gaps, which you can then incorporate into your routes around the map. Speaking of routes...
- **Know the Map**: Try to deliberately use a good chunk of the map. I admittedly don't know if this is truly the case, but it seems when I use more of the map my scores are higher. I try to plan some rough routes out in advance that will touch on the points above - find a route that will allow you to chain different types of moves (grinds, manuals, flips, wall-plants, etc) while using some of the different gaps.